# Are there any way to create singular-name DB table?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

- development environment
  Lnaguage  : Golang ver.1.9.2
  DB        : mySQL
  Framework : not decided (Maybe I'll use revel)
- situation
  I already have DB which has singular-name table ,like "user", "page". It can't be changed.

  Now I'll develop new application using this DB.
  I created simple application to connect this DB, and tried to auto migrate using gorm(https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm).
  I defined some models, like "user" which is same as existing DB table name, and run auto-migrate just as it written in (http://jinzhu.me/gorm/database.html#connecting-to-a-database )

  db.Set("gorm:table_options", "ENGINE=InnoDB").AutoMigrate(&User{})

  Then, new table "users" was created.
- Question
  Can I create singular-name table, like "user" with auto-migrate or those things ?
  Using gorm is not required, so I'll use another orm library if it works.

I hope anyone help me !

Comment: Not a gorm user but if you do ctrl+f on its docs you can see https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.SingularTable, maybe try that.

Comment: If you aren't married to gorm, what's wrong with `CREATE TABLE foo`?

Comment: SingularTable func works well  ! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement function `TableName` on struct `User` to return a custom name for the table. The ORM uses this function to get the table name for all DB operations.

```
func (user *User) TableName() string {
    return "user"
}
```

Refer docs here: http://jinzhu.me/gorm/models.html#table-name-is-the-pluralized-version-of-struct-name

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's just I wanna do !

Answer (score 2):

You have set with db instance to use singular table, like this: 
`db.SingularTable(true)`